# How does docker manage to get a return code of 200 instead of 401

Tags: http, go, docker

At work docker is not able to pull images:

```
[b209d3c5] +job pull(ubuntu, )
[debug] registry.go:372 [registry] Calling GET https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images
[debug] http.go:160 https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images -- HEADERS: map[User-Agent:[docker/1.0.0 go/go1.2.2 git-commit/63fe64c kernel/3.15.1-1-ARCH os/linux arch/amd64]]
[debug] server.go:1182 Retrieving the tag list
[debug] http.go:160 https://cdn-registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/tags -- HEADERS: map[User-Agent:[docker/1.0.0 go/go1.2.2 git-commit/63fe64c kernel/3.15.1-1-ARCH os/linux arch/amd64]]
[debug] registry.go:327 Got status code 401 from https://cdn-registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/tags
[error] server.go:1185 Could not reach any registry endpoint
Could not reach any registry endpoint
[b209d3c5] -job pull(ubuntu, ) = ERR (1)
```

If I manually try to access that second URL it reliably results in a 401, too.

However at home the same command somehow manages to successfully retrieve the tags:

```
[4e9acee4] +job pull(ubuntu, )
[debug] registry.go:372 [registry] Calling GET https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images
[debug] http.go:160 https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images -- HEADERS: map[User-Agent:[docker/1.0.0 go/go1.2.2 git-commit/63fe64c kernel/3.14.6-1-ARCH os/linux arch/amd64]]
[debug] server.go:1182 Retrieving the tag list
[debug] http.go:160 https://cdn-registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/tags -- HEADERS: map[User-Agent:[docker/1.0.0 go/go1.2.2 git-commit/63fe64c kernel/3.14.6-1-ARCH os/linux arch/amd64]]
[debug] registry.go:327 Got status code 200 from https://cdn-registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/tags
[debug] server.go:1197 Registering tags
[...]
```

The question is: How did this docker instance manage to get a 200 result?

Is there a good way to inspect the communication? (Wireshark is probably not good as https is completely encrypted.)

Probably the only way is reading the [source code](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/server/server.go#L1159). But I don't know much about the go language.

Can you think of any better solution that, building docker on my own and adding some debugging prints?

Comment: There is also a [documentation](http://docker.readthedocs.org/en/v0.5.3/api/registry_index_spec/#tags-registry) for that kind of REST interface, but it does not specify any more requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that REST call [requires](http://docker.readthedocs.org/en/v0.5.3/api/registry_index_spec/#on-the-registry) a valid `Authorization: Token ...` header. Also seems like the company proxy breaks that header. :(

Building docker from source is really painless.